# How to use raise to the power of x in c

Tags: c

My question is how do I compute 2^(x) in c. I know there is something like shifting that does the same thing. I tried to do total = x << 1, but that didn't work. I know that if i shift one bit it is the same as multiplying it by two. Or something like that.

```
int x;

for(x=0; x<4; x++){

total += x <<1; // 

}
```

When this is done executing I expect the total to be 15 ( 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> )

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? my total starts off as being 0 and then messes up.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18733675/694576

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's the other way around. `1 << x` will give you '2 ^ x'.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want. Call `pow(2, x)` to get 2<sup>x</sup>.

```
int abs (int x) {
  if (x < 0) return -x;
  return x;
}

int signum (int x) {
  if (x < 0) return -1;
  if (x > 0) return 1;
  return 0;
}

int add (int x, int y) {
  for (int i = 0; i < abs(y); ++i) {
    if (y > 0) ++x;
    else --x;
  }
  return x;
}

int mult (int x, int y) {
  int sign = signum(x) * signum(y);
  x = abs(x);
  y = abs(y);
  int res = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
    res = add(res, x);
  }
  return sign * res;
}

int pow (int x, int y) {
  if (y < 0) return 0;
  int res = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
    res = mult(res, x);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Left shift is limited to the word size of your CPU, either 32 or 64 bits, which limits the maximum exponent which you can safely use, before the result is undefined (2^31 or 2^63).

The following works for larger exponents but uses floating point arithmetic. If you need exact results you should consider using a infinite precision maths library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double base = 2;
  double exponent = 4;

  double result = pow(base, exponent);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ldexp` is the right way to do this with floating point, but both `ldexp` and `pow` should **always** give exact results unless the result overflows (to infinity) or underflows (to zero).