# To the power of in C?

Tags: c, math

So in python, all I have to do is

```
print(3**4)
```

Which gives me 81

How do I do this in C? I searched a bit and say the `exp()` function, but have no clue how to use it, thanks in advance

Comment: You want `pow` rather than `exp`. See if that's enough of a hint.

Comment: "incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'pow' "

Comment: Are you sure that `print(3**4)` would give you `12` in python?

Comment: wow, I was thinking of multiplication when I wrote that, sorry, *81

Comment: @samir Jon is right. The error you're getting most probably depends on you not having included the relevant header file: put `#include <math.h>` at the top of your program (I hope you know what an *include directive* is and what it is used for).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHosLhPEN3k

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need `pow();` function from `math.h` header.
**syntax**

```
#include <math.h>
double pow(double x, double y);
float powf(float x, float y);
long double powl(long double x, long double y);
```

Here x is base and y is exponent.  result is `x^y`.

**usage**

```
pow(2,4);  

result is 2^4 = 16. //this is math notation only   
// In c ^ is a bitwise operator
```

And make sure you include `math.h`  to avoid warning  ("`incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'pow'` ").

Link math library by using `-lm` while compiling. This is dependent on Your environment.
For example if you use Windows it's not required to do so, but it is in UNIX based systems.

Comment: Couple of minor points - first, `y` is an exponent, not exponential the _result_ is exponential (it's an adjective, not a noun). Second, there's nothing in C about linking with `-lm`, that's an implementation thing and, since OP didn't state their environment, it's unwise to assume.

Comment: @paxdiablo modified term exponential to exponent, added dependency on environment.thank you for pointing these.

Comment: @paxdiablo The function is exponential (adjective) with change in the exponent and the result is the power (noun) of the base to the exponent.

Comment: Clarification: When using `pow()` it is always necessary to include `math.h`. What is dependent on the environment is the "link math library" step.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson when ever if you want to use  pow() you should include math.h header file. Requirement of explicit linking is dependent.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. I see that you have edited the answer to make this more clear, which is good.

Answer (score 17):

you can use `pow(base, exponent)` from `#include <math.h>`

or create your own:

```
int myPow(int x,int n)
{
    int i; /* Variable used in loop counter */
    int number = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        number *= x;

    return(number);
}
```

Comment: The second argument is called the exponent. The result is called the power.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <math.h>


printf ("%d", (int) pow (3, 4));
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no operator for such usage in C, but a family of functions:

```
double pow (double base , double exponent);
float powf (float base  , float exponent);
long double powl (long double base, long double exponent);
```

Note that the later two are only part of standard C since C99.

If you get a warning like:

> "incompatible implicit declaration of built in function 'pow' "

That's because you forgot `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: makes more sense, thank you! :)

Comment: also, you probably want to include math library during compilation by adding -lm parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in C you don't have an power operator. You will need to manually run a loop to get the result. Even the exp function just operates in that way only. But if you need to use that function, include the following header

```
#include <math.h>
```

Then, you can use `pow()`.

Comment: thank you! is `include <>` the same as `import` in python?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know python, but it's same as java import, or c# using directive.  And yes, the # is important!

Comment: @samir It's not exactly same as *import* in many languages. C `#include` just inserts contents of included file into compilation, and you could achieve identical effect by writing right declarations yourself. In other languages, *import* works in more abstract level. But purpose is the same.

Answer (score 5):

For another approach, note that all the standard library functions work with floating point types. You can implement an integer type function like this:

```
unsigned power(unsigned base, unsigned degree)
{
    unsigned result = 1;
    unsigned term = base;
    while (degree)
    {
        if (degree & 1)
            result *= term;
        term *= term;
        degree = degree >> 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This effectively does repeated multiples, but cuts down on that a bit by using the bit representation. For low integer powers this is quite effective.

Answer (score 4):

just use `pow(a,b)`,which is exactly `3**4` in python

Comment: except that `pow` invokes floating point: in that case it's better to use 3*3*3*3 or do that with a loop or a smarter algorithm.