# c-changing string to int

Tags: c, string, int

I'm trying to change a string of chars into a number.
For example the string '5','3','9' into 539.
what I did is:

```
for (j = 0; j < len_of_str; j++)
     num = num + ((str[j] - 48) * (10 ^ (len_of_str - j)))    
printf("%d", num);
```

`num` is the number which would contain the number as a `int` the minus 48 is to change the value in ASCII to a number who's like the real number.
and the `(10 ^ (len_of_str - j))` is the change the values to hundreds, thousands, etc...

Comment: `^` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Unless it's the `^` next to good comments.

Comment: I suggest using `'0'`, it's much more readable than 48. And unless you're trying to read the number backwards, using `num = num*10 + str[j] - '0'` is much more better. But do you know what's even better? [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)

Comment: atoi isn't in every library oddly. It probably should be, but it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

First, `^` is not an exponentiation operator in C - it's a bitwise exclusive-OR operator.  Instead of getting 10<sup>N</sup>, you'll get 10 XOR N, which is not what you want.  C does not have an exponentiation operator (ironic for a language that defines eleventy billion operators, but there you go) - you'll need to use the library function `pow` instead.  Or you can avoid the whole issue and do this instead:

```
num = 0;
for ( j = 0; j < len_of_str; j++ )
{
  num *= 10;
  num += str[j] - 48;
}
```

Second, `str[j]-48` assumes ASCII encoding.  To make that a bit more generic, use `str[j] - '0'` instead (in most encodings digit characters are sequential,
so `'9' - '0'` *should* equal 9).

Finally, is there a reason you're not using one of the built-in library functions such as `atoi` or `strtol`?

```
num = (int) strtol( str, NULL, 0 );
printf( "num = %d\n", num );
```

Comment: The spec states that, *"In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after '0' in the [...] list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."* In other words, you should always use `str[j] - '0'` and it's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the comments above, `^` does not actually calculate a power, but instead does a bit-wise XOR (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)). For instance for `0101 ^ 0111 == 0010`, as XOR will only set the bits to one for which the inputs differ in that bit.

To calculate 10 to the power something in c, use `pow(double x, double y)` from `<math.h>`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733675/to-the-power-of-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a sequence of digits into an integer is a special case of the more general case of parsing a number (integer or real) into a binary integer or double value.

One approach is to describe the number using a pattern, which you can either describe iteratively, or recursively as follows,

```
An integer_string is composed of:
    and optional '+' or '-' (sign)
    follwed by a digit_sequence
a digit_sequence is composed of:
    digit ('0', '1', '2', '3', ..., '9')
    followed by an optional (recursive) digit_sequence
```

This can be written using Backus-Naur formalism as,

```
integer_string := { '+' | '-' } digit_sequence
digit_sequence := digit { digit_sequence }
digit := [ '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' ]
```

Should you desire, you can extend the above to recognize a real number,

```
real_number := integer_string { '.' { digit_sequence } }
               { [ 'e' | 'E' ] integer_string }
```

Although the above is not quite correct, as it forces a digit before the decimal (fix is left as an exercise for the reader).

Once you have the Backus-Naur formalism, it is easy to recognize the symbols that comprise the pattern, and the semantic action of the actual conversion to integer

```
long int
atol_self(char* str)
{
    if(!str) return(0);
    //accumulator for value
    long int accum=0; //nothing yet
    //index through the string
    int ndx=0;
    //handle the optional sign
    int sign=1;
    if ( str[ndx=0] == '+' ) { sign=1; ndx+=1; }
    else if ( str[ndx=0] == '+' ) { sign=1; ndx+=1; }
    for( ; str[ndx] && isdigit(str[ndx]); ) {
        int digval = str[ndx] - '0';
        accum = accum*10 + digval;
        ++ndx;
    }
    return(accum*sign);
}
```